# Setting mindate in datepicker on the bases of another datetimepicker selected date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to set mindate from another `datetimepicker` selected date in bootstrap datepicker. Is it possible to do this??

```html
<div class="form-group hide" id="divStartsOn">
   <div class="col-md-3">
       <label>Start On</label>
   </div>
   <div class="input-group col-md-9" style="padding-left: 14px;">
     <input id="datetimepicker8" type="text" class="date-picker form-control" />
     <label for="datetimepicker8" class="input-group-addon btn">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
     </label>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div> 

<div class="input-group col-md-6" style="padding-left: 14px;">
    <input id="datetimepicker9" type="text" class="date-picker form-control" />
    <label for="datetimepicker9" class="input-group-addon btn">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) { 
    var sdate = $('#txtdatetimepicker1').val().split('/'); 
    sdate[2] = sdate[2].substring(0, 4); 
    var stdate = sdate[0] + "/" + sdate[1] + "/" + sdate[2];   
    $("#datepicker8").datepicker("option", { minDate: stdate }) 
});
```

Comment: please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: `$("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            var sdate = $('#txtdatetimepicker1').val().split('/');
            sdate[2] = sdate[2].substring(0, 4);
            var stdate = sdate[0] + "/" + sdate[1] + "/" + sdate[2];
            $("#datepicker8").datepicker("option", { minDate: stdate })
        });`

Comment: I already shared code

Comment: You should edit the question and add the relevant code instead adding it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this is by removing datpicker.js and add jquery.ui.js after jquery.js